# rsync - target bigger then source?

Tags: rsync, hard-link

I have a harddrive for backups @ /mnt/old/

am making a copy of a folder (/mnt/old/backup/) that occupies a large part of the partition it's located on.

```
$ df -h /mnt/old/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde1       917G  917G     0 100% /mnt/old
```

now copying the content of that backup folder with rsync (`rsync -Aav /mnt/old/backup/* /mnt/new/backup/`

now ... while doing so I am going hugely over the size of the entire `old` partition already (and it's still runiing

```
$ df -h /mnt/new/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       1.8T  944G  798G  55% /mnt/new
```

I don't get it ... Only thing the main part of the files to be copied are many instances or links to the same inode's. Can it be that those links are being copied as separate files now?

Answer (score 0):

> Can it be that those links are being copied as separate files now?

I look in the manpage explains it ...

```
 -H, --hard-links
              This tells rsync to look for hard-linked files in the source and link together the corresponding files on  the  destination.  Without  this  option,
              hard-linked files in the source are treated as though they were separate files.
```

... which is apparently what is happening here ... so just forgetting about the past hours and trying `rsync -Aav -H /mnt/old/backup/* /mnt/new/backup/`